# Navigating throughout screens android develpment

Tags: java, android, navigation

Hello just wondering if someone could help me, I'm new to JAVA (android development programming) done a bit of HTML and C# that's about it. I've recently 
decided to create an application and can't figure out how to navigate through the screens, home screen to exercises and so on. There will be about 30 screens 
(pages) within the application each describing an exercises including images. I'm wondering what's the best way to complete this chore?
I've created 2 XML files as shown below.

**Activity_main.xml**

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#808080"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="184dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/description"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#FFFF00"
            android:textSize="26sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/exercise"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/exercises"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="myClickHandler" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/routines"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:src="@drawable/routines" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logbook"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logbook" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/qrscanner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:src="@drawable/qrscanner" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Copyright"
            android:layout_width="206dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="220dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:text="@string/copyright"
            android:textColor="#FFFF00"
            android:textSize="14sp" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/Logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="230dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-440dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logov2" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

**Also an exercises.xml**

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="452dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Logo"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="230dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logov2" />

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/chest"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
         android:src="@drawable/chest_exercises" />

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/shoulder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-82dp"
        android:src="@drawable/shoulderexercises" />

         <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="230dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-82dp"
        android:src="@drawable/backexercises" />

        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bicep"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/bicepexercises" />

        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tricep"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-82dp"
        android:src="@drawable/tricepexercises" />


       <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/abbs"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="230dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-82dp"
        android:src="@drawable/abbsexercises" />

        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/quad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/quadexercise" />

        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/calves"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-82dp"
        android:src="@drawable/calvesexercises" />

         <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/glutes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="230dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-82dp"
        android:src="@drawable/gluteexercises" />

        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/hamstring"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/hamstringexercises" />


        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/traps"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-82dp"
        android:src="@drawable/trapexercises" />

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="184dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-470dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/musclegroup"
        android:textColor="#FFFF00"
        android:textSize="26sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I'm just wondering how can I navigate from home screen to exercises.xml?
Is it ok if i use imageviews as buttons?

Thanks in advance
Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using Buttons and setting the images as backgrounds. Images are quite bitchy sometimes when it comes to recognize touch.
So the navigation would eg be homescreen -> click on exercise image -> click on body part -> see exercises?
With that number of items just images/buttons are totally ok, but if your submenues get larger you should start thinking of ListViews for performance.
If you have a hierarchy like that, you could either do a new Activity for every new Screen, or use Fragments. Fragments are smoother when you go trough the screens, but with a clear hierarchy like that I would recomment to start off with activities.
Activities won't allow you to keep a constant tabbar, because you will be really exchanging the whole screen, but if there is no element you want to keep the same on every screen that should not be a problem.

In my oppinion Fragments are a nicer way to do almost everything. The thing is, Fragments are much more complicated for a beginner. So if you have some time, go ahead and dive into Fragments, but if you are in a hurry just calling a Activity for every screen should be fine for this scenario.

Comment: Yeah your navigation was bang on, that's how it's going to work. I've never used fragments before, is this hard? I recently tried the onclicklistener method for the buttons but I couldn't get it to work at all! Do you know of any simple but effective tutorials? Thank you

Comment: The best way to imageine Fragemnts are as a mixture of Activity and View. They are almoust as mighty as Activities, but can be shown only on parts of the underlying Activity. The transition between them is very smooth. You would add a Fragment in the Activity. When finished in that Fragment, you would do a callback, maybe in a onClick, which would call a function in your Activity. There you can replace the Fragment by the next Fragment.  
I found the concept of Fragments quite difficult,  but once learned they are very easy to use and look great.

Comment: For tutorials I would also recommend the mykong tutorials, they are pretty good because they only explain what you need.
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-button-example/  
    
For Fragments there are a few good ones in this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710573/need-a-fragments-example

Answer (score 0):

Typically what you want to do is either use Fragments (which I would suggest) or a new Activity to show the different xml files.

To copy some code from: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html, this is the preferred way to do this.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager()
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
ExerciseFragment fragment = new ExerciseFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Using ImageViews as buttons is perfectly valid, as long as it's obvious to the user that's what they are. Your handler code could look like this:

```
public void myClickHandler(View view){
    int id=view.getId();
    if(id==R.id.exercises){          
        doSomething()
    }else if(id=R.id.logbook){
    }....
}
```